# How to increase the length of top rule and mid rule

Tags: tables, spacing

I have a problem with my LaTeX code, the length of top rule, mid rule and bottom rules were not fit in accordance with the data. How can I change the length of the rules of the table so that caption and column names are clearly separated?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=newline,
              singlelinecheck=false,
              skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}} % "decimal" column type
\renewcommand{\ast}{{}^{\textstyle *}} % for raised "asterisks"
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out amount of inter-column whitespace
    \caption*{MNI maximum coordinates,cluster size,p-values of resting state statistical maps for seed Cornu Ammonis.}
    \label{turns}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{20}{d{2.4}} }
    \toprule
     \multicolumn{1}{c}{Brain area} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cluster size } && \multicolumn{1}{c}{Coordinates} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{p-unc} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{p-FDR} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{p-FWE}\\
     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(voxels)} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{x y z} & \\
    \midrule
    Right inferior parietal lobule      & 132 & -0.002 & 1.155\ast \\
                  & (1.22)    & (2.22) & (0.56)\\
    Right inferior occipitofrontal fasciculus      & 0.025\ast & -0.002 & 1.155\ast \\
                  & (1.22)    & (2.22) & (0.56)\\
    Right visual cortex V5 
                  & 0.025\ast & -0.002 & 1.155\ast \\
                  & (1.22)    & (2.22) & (0.56)\\

    Right inferior parietal lobule 
                  & 0.025\ast & -0.002 & 1.155\ast \\
                  & (1.22)    & (2.22) & (0.56)\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you are asking: does the problem lies in the caption being too close to the table?  If so, try loading the `caption` package (if you are lucky, simply loading the package will solve the issue).

Comment: Please post a minimal working example so that we can more easily help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Check out the `makecell` package.

Comment: Where is the `d` colum defined? Where does `\caption*` come from?  It is pure luck if the combination of `table}[h]` and `landscape` works. So as others have mentioned please post a full minimal example others can copy and test as is.

Comment: Why do you define 21 columns, if you only seem to use 10 of them? You might also mant to use `{\linewidth}` instead of `{\textwidth}`.

Comment: @dexteritas I have edited my code, please kindly review it

Comment: @daleif i have edited the code , sorry for the confusion that you had, i have used the package caption

Comment: your problem is in discrepancy between defined numbers of columns and numbers of ampersands in rows of your table body. even you have most of cells empty, there still should be 20 ampersands: for example, instead of 
`Right inferior parietal lobule & 132 & -0.002 & 1.155\ast \\ `
should be 
`Right inferior parietal lobule & 132 & -0.002 & 1.155\ast &&&&&&& &&&&&&&&&&\\ `

Comment: Why do you have `&&` between your `\multicolumn`? Why did you define `*{20}` when your `d` columns are only 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the height of the page before going into landscape mode and then use that as the width of the table.  Put the following into the preamble, adding `\begin{document}`:

```
 \newlength{\saveheight}             
      \setlength{\saveheight}{\textheight} 
 \begin{document}
```

and then for starting your table use:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\saveheight}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{20}{d{2.4}} }
```

The output I get is below:
[image]

**Addendum**: I'm just seeing the recommendation of Leandiis, to use `\linewidth`, which is a simpler path to the same result.  (The use of `\savewidth` above enables further manipulation, e.g., `\addtolength{\saveheight}{\headheight}` etc. if you are in a two page format with headers.)